# Read connection setting from a text file

Tags: oracle11g, pentaho

I am developing a transformation (on pentaho 4.4.0) which basically reads data from one oracle DB (11g), makes some transformation and loads data into another Oracle DB. Now for DB table input/output when I need to select a connection I have to select it from a drop down menu in 'Edit Step'. When I edit the connection, it asks me settings, like Host name, database name, port number, user name, password.

What I want is, to create a text file called 'Pentaho_connection_properties' in some directory on my machine where I will save all these info and as soon as I choose a connection name from the connection drop down menu, Pentaho should automatically read the file and populate the settings corresponding to that connection name. The purpose is to get rid of this manual process to entering settings again and again for multiple use of same DB.

Please let me know how this can be done. I will appreciate if you can be little explicit since I am new to Pentaho.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Switch to using database repositories. Connection definitions are shared throughout an entire database repository.